# PHP variable like $myvar-test is not valid?

Tags: php

I need to create a var like `$myvar-test;` but thats not valid or?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not valid. The reason is the minus sign (-). In PHP, variables can contain 0-9a-zA-Z_ with the exception that it must not begin with a number and Unicode letters are allowed. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

> Variables in PHP are represented by a
>   dollar sign followed by the name of
>   the variable. The variable name is
>   case-sensitive.
>
> ```
> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
> ```
>
> variable name starts with a letter or
>   underscore, followed by any number of
>   letters, numbers, or underscores. As a
>   regular expression, it would be
>   expressed thus:
>   '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

And a couple of examples:

```
<?php
$var = 'Bob';
$Var = 'Joe';
echo "$var, $Var";      // outputs "Bob, Joe"

$4site = 'not yet';     // invalid; starts with a number
$_4site = 'not yet';    // valid; starts with an underscore
$täyte = 'mansikka';    // valid; 'ä' is (Extended) ASCII 228.
?>
```

Comment: According to your quote from the documentation, Unicode isn't allowed. Given PHP's very bad track record of supporting Unicode it would have surprised me, actually.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what the given regex in the documentation exactly matches (does it match Unicode letters?), but I can use even chinese characters if I wanted to like $華語 = 5; and define function names the same way.

Answer (score 4):

There are workarounds, but it's really, really ugly. Better use an underscore, or camelCase or an array where you can use any string as key names.

This would be the workaround:

```
${'a-b'} = 'foo';

var_dump(${'a-b'}); // string(3) "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dashes in variable names.

From the documentation:

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable. The variable name is case-sensitive.
>
> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Answer (score 0):

minus sign used for subtraction
you will end up with same result with variables like $myvar*test $myvar$test, $myvar;test $myvar(test and such.

Just don't use special syntax in the variables names.

Note that array key names may contain almost any character, even of national languages

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

So your variable name is invalid according to these rules.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid - but if you get it for example from JSON - here is a workaround:

```
print_r($JSONObject);

stdClass Object (
    [psr-0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [MyBundle] => 'MyPath' 
        )

)
```

...trying to access **$JSONObject->psr-0;** doesn't work - so you can cast **stdClass** to **Array**:

```
$JSONArray = (array)$JSONObject;
print_r($JSONArray);

Array
(
    [psr-0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [MyBundle] => 'MyPath' 
        )

)
```

...now you can easy access **$JSONArray['psr-0']**!