# php variable name and braces

Tags: php

A similar question was asked here: [PHP variable like $myvar-test is not valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690858/php-variable-like-myvar-test-is-not-valid)

And I've read the [PHP Userland Naming Guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.php)
Where it says:

> > Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

What I'm curious about is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2690951/671191) , and why these workarounds work: `${'0x00'}`, or this: `${'900'}`, or this `${'bad-name'}`.

My question has two parts... why does this work? The second part of my question: Would they be considered valid variables or would be considered something else (I'm not asking if they work, but what they would be classified as.)

Comment: Also you can have "invalid" variable names using the evil variable variables: `$a = "123"; $$a = "hello";` (This just assigned the value 'hello' to variable '$123', that is invalid, but it works)

Comment: Related: [Exotic names for methods, constants, variables and fields - Bug or Feature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417180/exotic-names-for-methods-constants-variables-and-fields-bug-or-feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link : http://cowburn.info/2008/01/12/php-vars-curly-braces/

the answers are :

- question 1: because what is inside the braces will be, more than the name of a variable, a key/value pair within the `$_GLOBALS` array.
- question 2: they would be part of the $Globals of your script, but you can't access to them with the regular `$var` notation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the parser actually isn't validating the expression inside { }. Althought, internally PHP uses a HashTable to store variables, so any string or number is valid.